# Subquery returns more than 1 row - Mysql with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: subquery

I have the next code in mysql:

```
("SELECT id_viaje, 
       (SELECT nombre 
        FROM   unidades, 
               viaje 
        WHERE  id_unidad = id_unidades), 
       (SELECT nombre 
        FROM   empleados, 
               viaje 
        WHERE  id_empleado = id_conductor), 
       (SELECT nombre 
        FROM   empleados, 
               viaje 
        WHERE  id_empleado = id_guarda), 
       (SELECT nombre 
        FROM   ciudad, 
               viaje 
        WHERE  id_ciudad = id_salida), 
       (SELECT nombre 
        FROM   ciudad, 
               viaje 
        WHERE  id_ciudad = id_llegada), 
       fecha_salida, 
       fecha_llegada 
FROM   viaje; ")
```

I have tried LIMIT 1 at the end of each one, I have replaced = with IN and i have no idea why is showing me this error:

```
22:30:30    SELECT ID_Viaje, (select Nombre from unidades, viaje where ID_Unidad IN (ID_Unidades)) , (select Nombre from empleados, viaje where ID_Empleado IN (ID_Conductor)) ,(select Nombre from empleados, viaje where ID_Empleado IN (ID_Guarda)) , (select Nombre from ciudad, viaje where ID_Ciudad IN (ID_Salida)) , (select Nombre from ciudad, viaje where ID_Ciudad IN (ID_Llegada)) , Fecha_Salida, Fecha_Llegada FROM viaje limit 1    

Error Code: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Please I need help very quickly!

Comment: From the error message I can see that you are applying limit 1 to the outer query.You need to apply Limit 1 in each sub-query. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

This error is returned when your subquery returns multiple rows when it is supposed to return a single row.

Your subquery logic is completely wrong. When you put a subquery inside a `SELECT` statement, you must be sure that the subquery will always return zero or one row.

What you can do now is putting a `LEFT JOIN` and use a few aliases in your query, like this:

```
SELECT id_viaje, 
       u.nombre AS unidade_nombre,
       e_con.nombre AS conductor_nombre, 
       e_grd.nombre AS guarda_nombre, 
       c_salida.nombre AS salida_nombre,
       c_llegada.nombre AS llegada_nombre, 
       fecha_salida, 
       fecha_llegada 
FROM   viaje v
LEFT JOIN unidades u ON v.id_unidad = u.id_unidades
LEFT JOIN empleados e_con ON e.id_empleado = v.id_conductor
LEFT JOIN empleados e_grd ON e.id_empleado = v.id_guarda
LEFT JOIN ciudad c_salida ON e.id_salida = c_salida.id_ciudad
LEFT JOIN ciudad c_llegada ON e.id_llegada = c_llegada.id_ciudad
;
```

Try running this in MySQL Workbench first and only if it runs successfully there then you should put it into your application code.

Also note that my code is not supposed to run in the first attempt. Please make any applicable corrections before running this code.

Read more about [MySQL joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and [MySQL subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `in` operator when subQuery returns more than one row.But in your case the sub query is also a problem.Please try to use  what suggested by Rachcha